# JQuery - TableSorter and Pager not working within a CFDIV/DIV

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, tablesorter, pager

Thanks for taking the time to look into my issue. Basically I have a Coldfusion search page containing a form that displays the search results within a DIV. When the form is submitted the contents of the div are refreshed with the new results from srch_results.cfm. Im unable to get the tablesorter and pager functionality to work within a DIV or CFDIV (on the srch_results.cfm). Here is my code:

### HOME.cfm

```
<cfoutput>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#request.relative_path#scripts/jquery.tablesorter/style.css" type="text/css" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="#request.relative_path#scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="#request.relative_path#scripts/jquery.tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="#request.relative_path#scripts/jquery.tablesorter/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js">    </script>  
</cfoutput>
<script type="text/javascript">  
        $(document).ready(function() {  
                $("#srch_results #tableOne").tablesorter({ debug: false, sortList: [[0, 0]], widgets: ['zebra'] })  
                        .tablesorterPager({ container: $("#srch_results #pagerTwo"), positionFixed: false })  
            $("#srch_results #tableOne .header").click(function() {  
                    $("#srch_results #tableOne tfoot .first").click();  
            });                  
        });      

    </script>  
<cfoutput>    

<cfajaximport tags="cfform,cfdiv">    

<script>  
    function doSrch() {  
        ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm('goSrch', '#request.relative_path#index.cfm?action=save_srch', callback, errorHandler);  
    }  

    function callback(text)  
    {  
         ColdFusion.navigate("#request.relative_path#index.cfm?action=srch_results", "srch_results");  
    }  

     function errorHandler(code, msg)  
    {  
         alert("Error!!! " + code + ": " + msg);  
    }  
</script>  



<fieldset>  
<legend>Search</legend>  

<cfform action="#request.relative_path#index.cfm?action=home" method="post" name="goSrch">  
<table align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="3">  
<tr>  
    <th>Customer Name</th>    
    <th>Customer Number (MCN)</th>  
    <th>Type</th>  
    <th>Status</th>  
    <th>Begin Date</th>  
    <th>End Date</th>  
    <th>&nbsp;</th>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
    <td><cfinput type="text" name="customer_nm" value=""></td>  
    <td><cfinput type="text" name="customer_mcn" value=""></td>  
    <td>
    <select name="rec_type">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="999">Advanced Features</option>
        <option value="186">Megacom</option>
        <option value="131">Readyline</option>
    </select>
    </td>  
    <td>  
    <select name="rec_status">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="COMPLETE">COMPLETE</option>
        <option value="FAIL">FAIL</option>
        <option value="PENDING">PENDING</option>
    </select>
    </td>  
    <td><cfinput type="datefield" name="begin_date" value=""></td>  
    <td><cfinput type="datefield" name="end_date" value=""></td>  
     <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doSrch();">Search</a></td>  
</tr>     
</table>  
</cfform>  

<!---<div id="srch_results"></div>--->  
<cfdiv id="srch_results" bind="url:#request.relative_path#index.cfm?action=srch_results" bindonload="true" />  

</cfoutput>  
</fieldset>
```

**srch_results.cfm
-------------------------------------------------------------**

```
<cfset getSrchResults = request.getData.getSrchResults(form_args=form_args)>

<table cellspacing="1" id="tableOne" class="tablesorter">   
<thead>  
<tr>  
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Click Header to Sort">Status</a></th>  
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Click Header to Sort">Customer Name</a></th>  
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Click Header to Sort">MCN</a></th>  
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Click Header to Sort">ISC</a></th>  
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Click Header to Sort">ID</a></th>  
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Click Header to Sort">Order Number</a></th>  
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Click Header to Sort">TOO</a></th>  
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Click Header to Sort">8YY</a></th>  
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Click Header to Sort">TN CUS</a></th>  
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Click Header to Sort">CD</a></th>  
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Click Header to Sort">SLS</a></th>  
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Click Header to Sort">NCON</a></th>  
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Click Header to Sort">SOA</a></th>  
    <th><a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Click Header to Sort">Message</a></th>  
</tr>  
</thead>  
<tbody>  
<cfoutput query="getSrchResults">  
<tr>  
    <td>#getSrchResults.col1#</td>  
    <td>#getSrchResults.col2#</td>  
    <td>#getSrchResults.col3#</td>  
    <td>#getSrchResults.col4#</td>  
    <td>#getSrchResults.col5#</td>  
    <td>#getSrchResults.col6#</td>  
    <td>#getSrchResults.col7#</td>  
    <td>#getSrchResults.col8#</td>  
    <td>#getSrchResults.col9#</td>  
    <td>#getSrchResults.col10#</td>  
    <td>#getSrchResults.col11#</td>  
    <td>#getSrchResults.col12#</td>  
    <td>#getSrchResults.col13#</td>  
    <td>#getSrchResults.col14#</td>  
</tr>  
</cfoutput>  
</tbody>  
<cfoutput>  
<tfoot>  
    <tr id="pagerTwo">  
        <td colspan="14">  
            <img src="#request.relative_path#img/first.png" class="first"/>  
            <img src="#request.relative_path#img/prev.png" class="prev"/>  
            <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>  
            <img src="#request.relative_path#img/next.png" class="next"/>  
            <img src="#request.relative_path#img/last.png" class="last"/>  
            <select class="pagesize">  
                <option selected="selected"  value="10">10</option>  
                <option value="20">20</option>  
                <option value="30">30</option>  
                <option  value="40">40</option>  
            </select>  
        </td>  
    </tr>  
</tfoot>  
</cfoutput>  
</table>
```

The table sorter and pager functionality work fine outside of the div/cfdiv. Is there something that should be executed/reexecuted within the div/cfdiv (ie within srch_results.cfm) to get the sorting and paging to work?

Comment: Did you try using `$(window).load(function(){` instead of `$(document).ready(function() {`?

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves me right you will need to re-run the bindings you are doing in your document.ready once the AJAX runs, so you will want to move that code into you callback function since the table won't exist at document.ready, instead it will exist after the callback function has run.

Comment: thanks for the response. Im fairly new with JQuery, so I apologize, but just to clarify "re-run the bindings" statement you are referring to this particular piece of code, correct? $("#tableOne").tablesorter({ debug: false, sortList: [[0, 0]], widgets: ['zebra'] }) .tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pagerTwo"), positionFixed: false })

Comment: Wouldn't re-initiating the code above after the callback function be the same as adding it to the top of the srch_results.cfm with the document.ready? If so, I have tried both, but neither attempts were successful. Ive also tried just re-initiating the tablesorter after the table in the srch_results.cfm file.

Comment: You need to be sure the #srch_results #tableOne is in the DOM before you try and attach the table sorter to it...I haven't done a ton with cfdiv, but when I used JSON to add html to a page I did something like this: I had a getJSON call that had a function(data), in there after I added the return json to a div I called a function which then did my bindings i.e. $('a[@id^addtocart_]'.click(function()... the code is older JSON but the same concept applies...

Comment: Thank you for the advice - Im still working on this. I will post my code once finished.

Comment: If you want update your original question with where you are at with it and I will take another look at it...